# Trying to implement all list activity in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my android app, I am trying to retrieve user-installed apps and put them into a Fragment. Unfortunately, there is no FragmentListActivity support so I am unsure what to do and I need help in order to work around it.

I tried to implement this except with a Fragment

http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android

Currently I have three scrollable tabs and fragments in each tab.

Below is my java code for the InstalledAppActivity:

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.javatechig.listapps.ApplicationAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class InstalledAppActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, container, false);


    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        boolean result = true;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.main_text: {
                displayAboutDialog();

                break;
            }
            default: {
                result = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void displayAboutDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.slogan));


        builder.setPositiveButton("Know More", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://javatechig.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No Thanks!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        try {
            Intent intent = packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

            if (null != intent) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(InstalledAppActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(InstalledAppActivity.this,
                    R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(InstalledAppActivity.this, null,
                    "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

**The onListItemClick method can never been called because there is no such thing as a FragmentListActivity. So I am unsure how to fix this and what to extend.**

**This causes an error also in my TabsPagerAdapter class which is also linked to the same source of the problem**

[image]

Essentially I am trying to fix it so the list can show up in my fragment activity.

Comment: there is a ListFragment if that might help you

Comment: A `FragmentActivity` is a `Fragment`, not an `Activity`. You need to modify/clone `InstalledAppActivity` to inherit from `Fragment` for your idea to work.

Comment: How would ListFragment help? and how exactly should I "modify/clone"?

Answer (score 0):

Change InstalledAppActivity to extend ListFragment instead.